# Trying to show ad after certain time using android webview

Tags: java, android, timer, admob

As I mentioned in the question title that I am trying to show ad after a certain time like after every 30 seconds. I am doing this because I am using WebView so in WebView I have no idea about if there is a way to control admob ads through the website which is being loaded inside the Android Webview. Below is my code from `MainActivity.java` right now the ad is showing but only at the time when application starts and after there is no ad so I just to show every after 30 seconds

```
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });


        //AdView mAdView;
        //mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        //AdRequest bannerRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        //mAdView.loadAd(bannerRequest);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-123256789123456/1234567890", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        interstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
                        interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                                super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdImpression() {
                                super.onAdImpression();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdClicked() {
                                super.onAdClicked();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    }
                });
```

I found this code as solution through the internet but I have no idea if the same code will work in my case or if there is any changes required in the code and lastly where should I place this code:

```
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.interstitialAd.show();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To show an ad after a certain time interval, you can use a Handler to schedule the ad display. In your case, you can modify your code as follows:

```
// Declare these variables at the beginning of your activity
  private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
  private Handler adHandler;
  private static final long AD_DELAY = 30000; // 30 seconds in milliseconds

  // Initialize your ad in onCreate or wherever is appropriate
  MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
  @Override
  public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus) {
   }
  });

  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

  InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub- 
   123256789123456/1234567890",adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() 
   {
@Override
public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
    MainActivity.this.interstitialAd = interstitialAd;

    // Schedule ad display after a delay
    adHandler = new Handler();
    adHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (MainActivity.this.interstitialAd != null) {
                MainActivity.this.interstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
            }
        }
    }, AD_DELAY);

    interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
        // Your callback methods here
    });
}

@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
  }
});
```

This code schedules the ad to display after a 30-second delay. You should place this code in your onCreate method or wherever it's appropriate for your app's flow. Once the InterstitialAd is loaded and the Handler fires after the specified delay, it will show the ad.

Remember to manage the adHandler and the interstitialAd variable properly in your activity's lifecycle to avoid memory leaks or issues when navigating between activities or fragments.